# Creating a timer with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, timer

I am creating a GUI that needs to have timer starting from 0 and counting up every second until it reaches a limit
This is the code I have right now

```
limit = 10
score = 0

def update():
    global score, limit
    time.sleep(1)
    score += 1
    ScoreL.configure(text=score)
    if score < limit:
        update()

ScoreL = tkinter.Label(window, text = score)
ScoreL.pack()
update()
window.mainloop
```

Right now this is increasing the score each second but it does not open the GUI until the score reaches the limit. How can I make it so the GUI opens when the score is 0 but will continue to update each second?

Comment: please fix your code indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.sleep()` will block tkinter mainloop from updating, so you can only see the result after the score reaches the limit because at that time tkinter mainloop takes back the control.

Use `.after()` instead:

```py
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

limit = 10
score = 0

def update():
    global score
    score += 1
    ScoreL.configure(text=score)
    if score < limit:
        # schedule next update 1 second later
        window.after(1000, update)

ScoreL = tkinter.Label(window, text=score)
ScoreL.pack()

window.after(1000, update) # start the update 1 second later
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the after method of window to call a function after a specified no of milliseconds.

To use that for a timer you would call after again at the end of the called function.

In the function you would increment score until it reaches the limit, you would then use the after_cancel method to 'stop' the timer.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def update(score, limit):
    score +=1
    if score < limit:
        ScoreL.configure(text=score)
        timer = window.after(1000, update, score)
    else:
        window.after_cancel(timer)
        ScoreL.configure(text='Game over')

limit = 10
score = 0
ScoreL = Label(window, text = score)
ScoreL.pack()
timer = window.after(1000, update, score, limit)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code has the same problem, it runs the update function 10 times before the window.mainloop is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

@acw1668 Nice, and very useful.  The basic code proved helpful in writing a simple timer in tkinter with an hours/minutes/seconds GUI.  Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

class mainwindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self, title): 
        self.seconds  = 0
        self.minutes  = 0
        self.hours    = 0
        self.text     = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds )
        self.carry_on = True

        self.master = Tk()
        self.master.title(title)
       
        # set up a main frame
        self.window = Frame(self.master, bd=0, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.window.grid( column = 0, row = 0)

        self.ScoreL = Label(self.window, text = self.text)
        self.ScoreL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSWE', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.btn1 = Button(self.window, text = 'Quit', bd = '5',  command = self.master.destroy)
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSWE', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.btn2 = Button(self.window, text = 'Start', bd = '5',  command = self.start)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='NSWE', padx=5, pady=5)

        self.btn3 = Button(self.window, text = 'Stop', bd = '5',  command = self.stop)
        self.btn3.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='NSWE', padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.master.mainloop()

    def update(self):
        self.seconds += 1
        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes += 1
        if self.minutes == 60:
            self.minutes = 0
            self.hours += 1
        self.text = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds )
        self.ScoreL.configure(text=self.text)
        if self.carry_on == True:
            # schedule next update 1 second later
            self.master.after(1000, self.update)

    def start(self):
        self.seconds  = 0
        self.minutes  = 0
        self.hours    = 0
        self.carry_on = True
        self.master.after(1000, self.update)

    def stop(self):
        self.carry_on = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainwin = mainwindow( "Timer" )
```